# Adding dynamic columns and data in a Flutter Table widget

Tags: flutter, mobile-application

I'm working on a Flutter project where I need to create a Table widget with dynamic columns and dynamic data within those columns. I'm looking for guidance or an example of how to achieve this.

Specifically, I want to:

1. Dynamically add columns to a Table widget based on certain conditions or user inputs.
2. Populate each column with dynamic data retrieved from an API or a local data source.
3. Ensure that the Table layout adjusts dynamically based on the number of columns and their content.

[image: Reference Image]

[REFERENCE WEB :  METATRADER5 SYMBOL TABLE](https://trade.metatrader5.com/terminal)

I want to do same as metatrader5 symbol table.